# How to display HTML/Javascript snippet on HTML page (plaintext) using python?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

I am trying to display an `error message on HTML page`.

Error message is combination of HTML/Javascript, as shown below.

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element 

    <div id="sidebar_item_Reports" style="height: 18px; white-space:nowrap;" onclick="
            if (window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.stopProp)
              Event.stopProp(event);
          " onmousedown="
            if(Global.Central!=null) {
            Global.Central.SelectItem('Reports',event);}
            " class="sidebar_item sidebar_item_selected listItemSelected_fill skinGradient">...</div> is not clickable at point (105, 67). Other element would receive the click: <div class="overlay_concerto" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div>
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

As I embed the same, t's considered as HTML objects.

1. How can I display the exact error message (as shown above, along with tags) on HTML page ?
2. I am trying to do this with python. Any python modules available for this ?

`<plaintext>` doesn't seem to work on recent HTML versions.
Tried `<pre> and <code>` tags also.

**Code:**

```
var = """WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element 

    <div id="sidebar_item_Reports" style="height: 18px; white-space:nowrap;" onclick="
            if (window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.stopProp)
              Event.stopProp(event);
          " onmousedown="
            if(Global.Central!=null) {
            Global.Central.SelectItem('Reports',event);}
            " class="sidebar_item sidebar_item_selected listItemSelected_fill skinGradient">...</div> is not clickable at point (105, 67). Other element would receive the click: <div class="overlay_concerto" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div>
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"""

file_handler = open("test.html, "w")
file_handler.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><body>"+var+"</body></head></html>")
```

**Output on HTML page:**

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element
...
is not clickable at point (105, 67). Other element would receive the click: (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Is this possible ? Can anyone please help me here ?

Comment: I think you should simply convert the whole error into a string by using error.toString() or String(error) and then pass it as inner html of some div

Comment: @Irfanwani : Entire error is of type 'str'

Comment: Try it. It will now be bound

Comment: @Irfanwani Nope, that didn't workout. It's same as what is mentioned as above output. Above code does the same what you mentioned.

Comment: This is possible. It happened with me once but that was by mistake. That is why, i don't remember how to do that. But it is possible

Comment: @Irfanwani Can you please help me here ? You can reuse my code above. It'll be of great help.

Comment: Doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let st = `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div id="sidebar_item_Reports" style="height: 18px; white-space:nowrap;" onclick="if (window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.stopProp)Event.stopProp(event);" onmousedown="if(Global.Central!=null) {Global.Central.SelectItem('Reports',event);}" class="sidebar_item sidebar_item_selected listItemSelected_fill skinGradient">...</div> is not clickable at point (105, 67). Other element would receive the click: <div class="overlay_concerto" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div>(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)`
    
let newStr = st.replace('<', '&lt;');
let latest = newStr.replace('>', '&gt;');
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = latest;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='d'>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**EXPLANATION:**

In html, if we want to print the tag name inside the page (same as your condition) we need to replace the angle brackets with `&lt;`(for `<`) and `&gt;` (for `>`).

So in your problem, as we cannot do that manually because it is an error message not some hand-written code. So i used javascript to relace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: Thank you Irfan. Does Document contain that entire error message ? Can you please explain ? I am familiar with python.

Comment: Understood that replacing concept. How about document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = latest; ? What's it doing it here ? Can we do it in python similar way ?

Comment: I just replaced as you mentioned above, that worked for me. Thank you so much Irfan.

Comment: Actually this is just going in front end. I dont this you need python here. but if you are getting error at the backend, you can pass that to the template and do the same as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = latest; gets the element with id = 'd' which here is a div and i am setting its inner html equal to the latest, which is the new string created.

Comment: Seems you are a complete beginner. You should learn javascript, DOM api i.e, how we manipulate the page using js, and learn some other basic things.

Comment: BTW as you mentioned python, which framework are you using in python.